# trac error : Unable to get database connection within 0 seconds

Tags: python, fedora, trac

Recently I tried to install Trac on my Fedora 15, but I got trouble.
I followed steps with this link: http://www.diybl.com/course/6_system/linux/Linuxjs/20100524/204237.html
Yeah, it was wonderful and finally it worked. But after I add a [header_logo] section in trac.ini, it came out this error. And I tried to delete the [header_logo] section, but strangely it wouldn't work. And I don't know why.

I have searched the internet and got this link: http://axcoto.com/blog/article/840.
Yeah, as this link says, it is a permission error. But even after I change all things to the top level of permission, it didn't work either. I must confess that I'm bored. Can anyone help me? Thanks with all my heart.

Comment: You must have changed/deleted something else.

Comment: hasienda is right. Paste your trac.ini

Answer (score 0):

The [header_logo] section is totally unrelated to the other issue - Trac complaining for not getting a connection to the Trac db backend.

Corresponding settings for that are in section [trac] (with default value):

- `database = sqlite:db/trac.db`
- more like user, passwd,... depending on your db type

Two more things to look at:

- create a second, fresh Trac environment and compare the trac.ini in it against the one you've possibly damaged (You know the diff command, don't you?)
- compare permission settings of your Trac db file /db/trac.db

Comment: I have checked that but the [trac] section is all right. But I still get stuck here. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem too when I had the migrate an old SVN/Trac system to an internally available legacy box and it turned out that SQLite wasn't installed on my system.

I'm on Ubuntu and simply had to do a:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite
```

For me this solved the problem.